# Strange focus bug in Firefox (chrome vs content)

Tags: firefox, focus

Here is a strange bug I'm experiencing in Firefox: I can only use either the chrome, or the content, not both at the same time!

For example, I can click on tabs and the toolbar icons, focus the search bar and write in it as well as the address bar, but if I try to click on anything in the content (eg a link or a textfield to write something), then nothing happens. The mouse pointer doesn't change either, it just stays a pointer when I hover over things, and the links I hover don't react either.

But if I alt-tab to another program (or click on it in the taskbar), then back to Firefox, then I can use the area that I click on. So if I click somewhere on the webpage to get focus back to Firefox, then I can click on links and write things (like this text), but I cannot click on tabs or refresh or anything else in the chrome. I can't even click on the minimize, restore and close icons! To get focus back on the chrome I have to alt-tab to another program, and then click on the chrome to get back to Firefox to be able to use the chrome again.

I've tried closing and starting it again, but the bug is still there. I have experienced this before, but I don't remember what I did to fix it. This bug seems to occur sometimes when I wake up the computer from standby, but I leave by computer in standby all the time, so that is not the only factor.

Comment: Have you cleaned your keyboard? Maybe you have a key stuck.

Comment: What key would that be? I can still tab my self around the interface and the webpage, and it responds to other keyboard shortcuts (eg ctr+tab, F5)

Comment: Same problem i am facing for last few days.This problem started from the time of chrome installation on my laptop . So i uninstalled firefox and using chrome only..Wants to know the reason now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix, try re-installing the app. I know not the answer your looking for, but obviously something has changed or become corrupted, so re-install and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: I use Firefox 3.5 for day to day work, but I also have Firefox 3.6b1 and 3.7a1 installed, and the same bug is in those browsers too, even using other profiles. I also started a new session, but the bug still sticks around.

Comment: So the only similarity is its on the same pc? how about extensions, themes anything else that is similar

Answer (score 0):

Try [creating a new profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) and see if the issue still occurs. If it does, it's likely a problem with your Firefox installation and you should attempt a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted windows, and now the problem is gone, which is good, but a bit strange. I have no idea why it occurred, or why it got fixed when I restarted windows.

Comment: Posting something as a bug before restarting the system is pretty much overhasty, I think.